# How to download img with JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `<img id="barcode">` and  I need to download image from `src`. The image is generated with base64, and `src` contain this string:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

How to download this image with jquery?
I m trying to do this:

```
$('#save_but').click(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('barcode');
    img.src =$('#barcode').attr('src');
    window.location.href = img.src.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
});
```

File is downloading but I cannot assign name and format (example: img.png) to it.

Comment: Take a look at FileSaver.js: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score 5):

you can use the download attribute on an a tag ...

```
<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ..." download="filename.jpg"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ..."/></a>
```

see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/a#attr-download

Comment: what version of ie?

Comment: users using ie ver. 9+

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's solution for my problem:

1) Download this 5kb plugin: [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html)

2) Write

```
<script>
$('#save_but').click(function() {
download($('#barcode').attr('src'),"strcode.png","image/png");
});
</script>
```

Working in Chrome, FireFox, IE ver. 9+

Comment: Does not work, the first attribute should be a blob or binary data URL

Answer (score 0):

HTML File:

```
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px; padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
      <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr />
      <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
         Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
      </h3>
      <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
      <b>Codepedia.info</b> is a programming blog. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net,C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs, Web Design, Software
      </p>
      <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
      <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the user's browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
      </p>
</div>

<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
<br />
<div id="previewImage" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Inside the Script tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
       var getCanvas; // global variable

         html2canvas(element, {
             onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                   getCanvas = canvas;
                }
             });

         $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
           var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
           // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
           var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
           $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
           });
         });

 </script>
```